# Not show all links for Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In my Spring Boot project:

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'war' // to use JSP
}

group = 'ru.otus.sd'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    implementation 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.2'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

here application.yml

```
managment:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
          - beans
          - health
          - metrics
          - env

server:
  port: 8090
```

open `http://localhost:8090/actuator`
and here result:

```
{
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "http://localhost:8090/actuator",
"templated": false
},
"health": {
"href": "http://localhost:8090/actuator/health",
"templated": false
},
"health-path": {
"href": "http://localhost:8090/actuator/health/{*path}",
"templated": true
},
"info": {
"href": "http://localhost:8090/actuator/info",
"templated": false
}
}
}
```

Why not links like : **/beans**, **/metrics** ?

Comment: can you try with configuration 

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: info, health, metrics
  metrics:
    export:
      atlas:
        enabled: false

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try either of the below configurations

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: info, health, metrics
  metrics:
    export:
      atlas:
        enabled: false
```

Comment: But when I try to open /beans I get error page:Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not write JSON: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties. Forgot to register a type adapter?; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties. Forgot to register a type adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I have added the below configuration in `application.yml` and getting the metrics and beans in actuator details

```
management:
  server:
    port: 9000
  endpoint:
    shutdown:
      enabled: true  
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
        - beans
        - health
        - metrics
        - env
```

If you have use the same `application.yml` as you gave in question then please change the spelling of `management` as you write it as `managment`, as with wrong spell, I was also not getting the metrics and beans.